# Sometimes wget library gives error: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, wget

I am writing a script to download some videos in python.  For some reason I use wget directly through the subprocess module.  The script runs normally, but sometimes the above error occurs.

Comment: put the full error stacktrace in the question.

Comment: Python also has libraries to download files

Comment: it's not python's fault so there's no traceback, it's output when running wget

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add minimal reproducible example, or at least an attempt. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask